# New element on a php array file

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a total noob on php, but a friend of mine asked for help and I thought I might do it.. 
I have this code/file here and want to find a way to add an element in this array via html file. I know it sounds noob, it does for me too, but please help, I've seen arrays, vectors and lists only on c++, tried to take a look at the documentation of php5 (since he want it in php 5) but I couldn't make it!

here it is...

```
<?php    
$bledi = array('user12345', 'user2016', 'user5749852',  'user985658', 'HowToAddANewElement');
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, not just the array, also please elaborate what you mean by "add element to array via html file"

Comment: something like ... a seperate php/html file, that when i put submit or enter, with a designed button, i can add an element on that array.

Comment: We are not a free coding service, we are not gonna write it for you.

Comment: [Push one or more elements onto the end of array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need a form with a text input in HTML and a send button.
- When the form is submitted to the action page there you could put
  your php.
- You can make a global `array ($bledi)` and you will have an if condition there that says something like

  ```
   if($_REQUEST['input_text'])
        $bledi[] = $_REQUEST['input_text'];
  ```